# how to change usb_cam parameters?

Tags: ros, camera, dynamic-reconfigure, visp-auto-tracker, usb-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I have installed usb_cam package. And making use of it with visp_auto_tracker:

> ```
> roslaunch visp_auto_tracker tracklive_usb.launch
> ```

But the camera looks quite bright, i would like to edit those parameters (brightness, contrast, etc.) as easily as with dynamic_reconfigure and uvc (which i used for a totally different project):

> ```
> rosrun dynamic_reconfigure dynparam set /uvc_cam_node contrast 90
> ```

Please help.

Greetings ROS community.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57596/how-to-change-usb_cam-parameters?/) by [aimc](https://answers.ros.org/users/3966/aimc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 216 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aimc](https://answers.ros.org/users/3966/aimc/) on 2013-03-10**:
I found a "workaround" for my petition: guvcview will configure the webcam, whenever i quit guvcview the changes modified (with the graphical interface) will remain when launching with visp_auto_tracker .
However, it still lacks the functional properties of dynamic_reconfigure , for example dumping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

did you try rqt_rconfigure ?

```
rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure
```

---

Originally posted by [fatihx](https://answers.ros.org/users/5430/fatihx/) with karma: 26 on 2013-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BJP](https://answers.ros.org/users/30235/bjp/) on 2017-05-12**:
usb_cam does not currently provide dynamic_reconfigure access to camera parameters, so running this command will not do anything to address the question (though it will provide access to compression settings in image_transport)